# Xpages: Search box for data table

Tags: search, datatable, xpages, lotus-notes

i have a DataTable on my Xpage. I´ve filled with JavaScript an array with elements from 4 Notes Databases, which i´ve returned to the Table to show it on the DataTable.

This works, but now i need a search (edit box with search button) to search and update the results in the DataTable.

Is this possible? I only found a solution for a datatable, which is directly bind to a view, and nothing for a "manually" filled DataTable.

This is my Datatable code , which includes the JS code to create the array

```
<xp:dataTable id="dataTable3" rows="990" var="coll2Test"
                style="width:70%" indexVar="idx">


                <xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:pager partialRefresh="true"
                        layout="Previous Group Next" 
xp:key="header" id="pager8">
                    </xp:pager>
                </xp:this.facets>


                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:


var fa:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(@DbName()[0], "???????");
var faSh:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(@DbName()[0],"???????");
var faKb:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(@DbName()[0],"???????");
var fa20:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(@DbName()[0],"???????");


var vFa:NotesView = fa.getView("???????");
var vSh:NotesView = faSh.getView("???????");
var vKb:NotesView = faKb.getView("????????");
var v20:NotesView = fa20.getView("???????");


var doc:NotesDocument = vFa.getFirstDocument();
var docSh:NotesDocument = vSh.getFirstDocument();
var docKb:NotesDocument = vKb.getFirstDocument();
var doc20:NotesDocument = v20.getFirstDocument();


var faArr= new Array();


while(doc!= null) {

var eintrag = new Array();
eintrag.push(doc.getItemValue("Name"));
eintrag.push(doc.getItemValue("Description"));

faArr.push(eintrag)

doc = vFa.getNextDocument(doc);


}

while(docSh!= null) {

var eintrag = new Array();
eintrag.push(docSh.getItemValue("Name"));
eintrag.push(docSh.getItemValue("Description"));

faArr.push(eintrag)

docSh = vSh.getNextDocument(docSh);

}

..... 
//another 2 while
...




return faArr;}]]></xp:this.value><xp:table>
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xp:label 
value="Suche:"     id="label14"


style="font-        weight:bold">
                            </xp:label>
                        </xp:td>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xp:inputText    
id="inputText7"
                                value="#
{viewScope.searchView6}">


                            </xp:inputText>
                        </xp:td>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xp:button value="suchen"
                                id="button7">
                                <xp:eventHandler 
event="onclick"


submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="false"

save="true" id="eventHandler7">
                                </xp:eventHandler>
                            </xp:button>
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                </xp:table>









                <xp:column id="column6">
                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:label id="label11" 
xp:key="header"

style="color:rgb(0,128,255);font-weight:bold"
                            value="Name">

                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:text escape="false" 
id="computedField5">


                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#
{coll2Test[0]}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
                </xp:column>
                <xp:column id="column7">
                    <xp:this.facets>
                        <xp:label id="label12" 
xp:key="header"

style="color:rgb(0,128,255);font-weight:bold"
                            value="Description">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:this.facets>
                    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField6">

                        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#
{coll2Test[1]}]]></xp:this.value>
                    </xp:text>
                </xp:column>

            </xp:dataTable>
```

Regards

Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your completely filled JavaScript array into a **view scope variable** e.g. viewScope.AllEntries at the beginning. Fill your DataTable with

- the complete array if no search string is entered.
- the values matching search string if user entered a search string

This way you only need to read the data once from your four views and just filter it later depending on search string.

Move your code to `beforePageLoad` event. Add at the top

```
if (viewScope.AllEntries) {
    return;
}
```

and replace the last line `return faArr;` with

```
viewScope.AllEntries = faArr;
```

This way you'll calculate faArr only once and store it in viewScope.AllEntries.

Replace your code in DataTable "value" with:

```
if (!viewScope.search) {
    return viewScope.AllEntries;
}
...create and return an array (walking through viewScope.AllEntries)
...which contains only elements with search string viewScope.search
```

The search field can be an edit field bound to a viewScope like viewScope.search. Trigger a partial refresh of DataTable when user clicks on search button.

Comment: You can store the array in viewScope variable like this: `viewScope.AllEntries = myArray` in SSJS. It would be easier to help you if you would add your DataTable source code to your question...

Comment: Hi Knut, i´ve posted the DataTable Code to my question above